Advice on adding a covered patio in Atlanta metro
I'm looking to add a covered patio or deck to my home.
My house is 2,500 sq. ft. with 4 bedrooms and 2.5 baths, built on a slab foundation. Currently, there's a 14' x 10' concrete pad in the backyard, with a 6" drop from the house floor to the pad.
I want to upgrade this by adding a 20' x 20' concrete patio with a smooth finish, covered by a roof (maybe a lean-to or whatever style is most appropriate). It’s essential that the patio includes lighting and a ceiling fan. I'm also debating whether it’s worth it to have the patio screened in.
I’m open to ideas on the best type of patio to go with, and if anyone has contractor recommendations, I’d really appreciate it!
Also any ideas on what something like this costs right now? Ballpark?
https://i.imgur.com/ngcaZqq.jpeg
https://i.imgur.com/XYOuwIe.jpeg

We do not do costs.  Too much change.  Contractor recommendations is best from friends/neighbours.  Best is what you like/want, which we do not know.  We deal with how to do stuff(make/cut/attach).

The best advice we can give is to have a clear idea of what you want, in writing, and get quotes from at least 3 contractors.  We don't do "opinion-based" here either, so you may want to consider looking at neighbors or just general HGTV-type websites for ideas.

how is number of bedrooms and bathrooms relevant to the question?
